# PNG Files not found, when loaded in Server

Tags: html, ftp, png

Below are images of the my errors and sample code in my website calling the images. It gives me an 404 error saying it can not find my images in the server, when they are clearly there. Other images on the site work just fine. It's these profile photos that seem to not work.

[image: Error on Developer Tools]

[image: FTP Files Image]

[image: Sample Image code in Website]

Comment: right click, open in new tab. try if you can see the image

Comment: What websever it is... Make sure your server allowing .png files
https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_block_direct_hot_linking_to_image_files_using_htaccess%3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong with your `src` case.

You've written the directory `Team Photos` at `src` is in uppercase `assets/images/Team Photos/Lee.png`.

But, in your second image you've mentioned I see the directory is in lower case.

So, replace your `src` with `assets/images/team photos/Lee.png`.

Comment: This is probably the answer...it is also generally a better idea to leave out whitespace in paths, for example team photos may be less prone to errors if you change the Server OS, if the directory was changed to **team_photos**

Comment: @ViaTech Yes. White Spaces causes problems. But, he should be active and let us know if he trying our suggestion or fixed it or have trouble yet.